# Speed Up Xcopy in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

So I'm trying to copy a backup of the data from my app. I wrote the batch script below to do this, but the script takes forever to run.

I start the batch script at 1am, and it is still running at 8:30am. This seems weird to me because when I copy the backup of my app manually in Windows File Explorer, it copies in 7-15 minutes depending on network traffic.

I `REM` the `%backupcmd% "C:\Program Files\App\App Server\Data\Backups" "%drive%\"` line. That was the original line of batch script I used to backup the data, and it worked efficiently up till a month ago.

So I tried the `xcopy` command with `/d`, so it would only copy source files that have been changed on or after that date (the current date), and the backups I'm copying are made at 12:01am every night and the copy backup script starts at 1am.

Any advice as to how to speed up my `xcopy` would be appreciated. If you think I should use `powershell` for this task too, I'm open to that option as well.

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set yyyy=%ldt:~0,4%
set mm=%ldt:~4,2%
set dd=%ldt:~6,2%

:: variables
set drive=Z:\RootSoft\App\Data Backups
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y /f /z

echo ### Backing up Backup...
REM %backupcmd% "C:\Program Files\App\App Server\Data\Backups" "%drive%\"
xcopy "C:\Program Files\App\App Server\Data\Backups" "Z:\RootSoft\App\Data Backups" /D:%mm%-%dd%-%yyyy% /s /c /e /h /i /r /y /f /z


:: use below syntax to backup other directories...
:: %backupcmd% "...source directory..." "%drive%\...destination dir..."

echo Backup Complete!
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

Comment: Does your script actually finish if you wait long enough? Are you sure it's not hung with an error or waiting on user input?

Comment: I've had the script run for 24 hours until the next scheduled script run time starts, and it still doesn't finish. The script never asks for user input, and the `/c` makes `xcopy` ignore errors while copying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try with `ROBOCOPY` and `/MT` switch which could accelerate the copy.

Also you can make some test by measuring the during process with `TimeThis` that can be found [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/win2000platform/timethis/1.00.0.1/NT5/EN-US/timethis_setup.exe) (no need to be installed, just extract the `exe` with `7z` in the current batch file folder)

Comment: @pHorseSpec It seems so https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Comment: Cool, I'll see if that speeds up the copying

Comment: It made copying significantly faster!

Comment: Thanks. Experienced 3x speedup with ROBOCOPY vs XCOPY with ~2500 small files

Comment: '/MT:n' param has a argument 'n' to indicate the number of threads to be used, this number is between 1 and 128. ex: /MT:32

Answer (score 0):

- netsh interface tcp show global
- netsh int tcp set heuristics disabled
- netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
- netsh int ip set global taskoffload=disabled